# Can't login to a new mysql user

Tags: mysql, redhat, login

When I create a new Mysql user, it is impossible to login using this user and password. Only  if I crate a user without a password I can login.

For example:

```
mysql -u root -phererootpass
 grant all privileges on mydb.* to testuser@'%' identified by '' with grant option;
 grant all privileges on mydb.* to testuser2@'%' identified by 'mypass' with grant option;
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
 exit;

mysql -u testuser  #<<< work fine

mysql -u testuser2 -pmypass  #<<< fail to login
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'testuser2'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
</code>
```

I'm using Mysql 5.0 on Red Hat v5

Please advice
Mostar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've set up only allows you to connect from all other servers *other than* localhost.  You need to run this as well

```
grant all privileges on mydb.* to testuser2@'localhost' identified by 'mypass' with grant option;
```

And then remember to flush your privs.

Comment: @mostar - you may want to visit stackoverflow.com.  You'll find that this topic is covered more there.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the environment variable MYSQL_PWD?

export MYSQL_PWD='mypass'
mysql -u testuser2 -p

In my experience passing the password as a part of the CLI is a bad idea.
(it will show up in your process list for any user to see with 'top')